# NHibernate: insert multiple items at once

Tags: nhibernate

all! I am learning NHibernate now and I would like to know is it possible to save multiple objects to database in one operation.

For example, consider this test code

```
    private static void SaveTestBillNamesInSession(ISession session, params string[] names)
    {
        var bills = from name in names
                    select new Bill
                        {
                            Name = name,
                            DateRegistered = DateTime.Now,
                        };
        foreach (var bill in bills)
            session.SaveOrUpdate(bill);
    }
```

This loop here generates many INSERT statements which may be sub-optimal in SQL Server 2008 which allows to include multiple data rows in one INSERT statement.

Is it possible to rewrite this code to make use of this functionality - insert all the data in one operation?

**Update**
OK, now it's really started to send everything in a single batch. Many thanks to all!

Comment: Do you mean the "insert-union thing"? Is that just syntactical sugar or does it also perform better?

Comment: @Paco: it performs better if it's a single query vs. many independent INSERTs. If all these INSERTs come in a single batch then it's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's something close to what you want.

If you set the `adonet.batch_size` configuration property to anything other than 0 (the default), NHibernate will send that many statements at once to SQL Server.

Comment: I agree with this answer, if you're not sure if it's batching the inserts or not, have a look at www.nhprof.com and use Ayende's tool to see what NHibernate is doing to the database under the covers.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer! I have read the whole NHibernate documentation, and didn't remember this detail, but that NHibernate was not designed for batch treatments. Thanks! =)